# How to set incremented ID values to div elements created on the fly using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV called `.number` that holds the number `456` as text. I basically, create three DIV elements on the fly using jQuery and as text, I set each digit from the `div.number` to each DIV element. How do I set an incremented ID value to the three DIV elements that are created on the fly?
And if there is a better way on how to create these three DIV elements on the fly, I'd be glad to expand my knowledge.

I've been trying to make work, but this is really beyond my knowledge...

**Javascript/jQuery code**

```js
var x = 1;
    var result = $('.result');
    var btn = $('button');

    btn.on('click', function(){
          var row1 = $('<div class="row" id="row__'+x+'"></div>');
          var row2 = $('<div class="row" id="row__'+x+'"></div>');
          var row3 = $('<div class="row" id="row__'+x+'"></div>');

          var stringToSplit = $('.number').text();
           
          row1.text(stringToSplit.charAt(0) + ' -> #' + x);
          row2.text(stringToSplit.charAt(1) + ' -> #' + x);
          row3.text(stringToSplit.charAt(2) + ' -> #' + x);

          result.append(row1, row2, row3);
          $(this).hide();
          x++;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="number">456</div>

    <div class="result">

    </div>
    <button>Get</button>
```

I expect the output of `4 -> #1` in the first DIV, `5 -> #2` in the second DIV, `6 -> #3` in the third DIV,

Comment: This is an odd thing to do. Why do the elements need to have IDs? Or is that just a requirement?

Comment: Why would you expect those results when `x` is the same value for all three rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
var result = $('.result');
    var btn = $('button');

    btn.on('click', function(){
          var x = 3;
          var stringToSplit = $('.number').text();
          for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
              var div = $('<div class="row" id="row__'+(i+1)+'"></div>');
              div.text(stringToSplit.charAt(i) + ' -> #' + (i+1));
              result.append(div);
          }

          $(this).hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the `x`'s value while appending it to the `row1`, `row2` and `row3` text. You did increment the `x` but at the end of the handler function so no updated values for `x` are printed.

If You don't hide the `button` once it's clicked, clicking it again and again will do the same (as you had) but it keeps on incrementing `x` so you'll have :

```
/** first click **/
4 -> #1
5 -> #1
6 -> #1

/** second click **/
4 -> #2
5 -> #2
6 -> #2

/** third click **/
4 -> #3
5 -> #3
6 -> #3

/** nth click **/
4 -> #n
5 -> #n
6 -> #n
```

So in order to get the correct values for the `x` variable you need to increment it while printing it into the `row*` variable. Also, `x` must be local to the handler function so that you'll have the wanted result even if you click the `button` more than once :

> in the next demo, the `button` doesn't get hidden to allow you to click it many times to see the results.

```js
var result = $(".result");
var btn = $("button");

btn.on("click", function() {
  var x = 1; /** x is now a local variable so it reinitialized each time thebutton is clicked **/
  var row1 = $('<div class="row" id="row__' + x + '"></div>');
  var row2 = $('<div class="row" id="row__' + x + '"></div>');
  var row3 = $('<div class="row" id="row__' + x + '"></div>');

  var stringToSplit = $(".number").text();

  row1.text(stringToSplit.charAt(0) + " -> #" + x++); /** x++: prints 1 and then increments **/
  row2.text(stringToSplit.charAt(1) + " -> #" + x++); /** x++: prints 2 and then increments **/
  row3.text(stringToSplit.charAt(2) + " -> #" + x); /** prints 3 **/

  result.append(row1, row2, row3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">456</div>
<div class="result"></div>
<button>Get</button>
```

Comment: Your answer pointed me where I was wrong and I learned valuable information as well. I could've chosen you, but hassanrrs modified the code as I was expecting to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jQueryster I tried to show where's you fault and nothing else. If it was for me, I'd do this in 4 lines.